# The telegram bot does not work(pyQiwi or aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, aiogram

Hello everyone I wrote a bot for a freelance tutorial order, the bot responds to messages, but there is a problem with payment, after entering the amount of replenishment, the bot does not respond, maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

**main.py code**

```
    import logging
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    
    import config as cfg
    import markups as nav
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
    import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

import config as cfg
import markups as nav
from db import Database
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

db = Database("database.db")
p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key=cfg.QIWI_TOKEN)

def is_number(_str):
    try:
        int(_str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здравствуй дорогой {0.first_name}!\n\nТвой процент удачи сегодня: 99%\n"
                                                 f"\nВаш баланс: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'ST':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '️Купить читы')

    elif message.text == '️Купить читы':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите игру!', reply_markup = nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Hot Новости':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите дату!', reply_markup = nav.newsMenu)

    elif message.text == '️Лайфхаки дня':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите жанр игры!', reply_markup=nav.LiHaMenu)

    elif message.text == 'О боте':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Хоешь узнать обо мне?!', reply_markup=nav.aboutthebotMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Профиль':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваш аккаунт'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

    #Читы для игр
    elif message.text == 'CS-GO':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [CS-GO] 110₽'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nОплата Qiwi/Сбер/Тинькофф', reply_markup=nav.buyCSMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Dota2':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Dota2] 110₽'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nОплата Qiwi/Сбер/Тинькофф', reply_markup=nav.buyDota2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'Call Of Duty:Black Ops':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Call Of Duty:Black Ops] 110₽'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nОплата Qiwi/Сбер/Тинькофф', reply_markup=nav.buyCallOfDutyMenu)

    elif message.text == 'PUBG':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [PUBG] 110₽'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nОплата Qiwi/Сбер/Тинькофф', reply_markup=nav.buyPUBGMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Standoff2':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Standoff2] 110₽'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nОплата Qiwi/Сбер/Тинькофф', reply_markup=nav.buyStandoff2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Новости для игр
    elif message.text == 'Today':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Today', reply_markup=nav.newsTMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Yesterday':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Yesterday', reply_markup=nav.newsYEMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Лайфхак для игр
    elif message.text == 'Шутеры':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [Шутеров] читай в Telegraph', reply_markup=nav.newsShootMenu)

    elif message.text == 'ММОРПГ':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [ММОРПГ] читай в Telegraph', reply_markup=nav.newsMMORPGMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Стратегии':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [Стратегии] читай в Telegraph', reply_markup=nav.newsStrategyMenu)

    elif message.text == 'MMO Action[скоро!]':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [MMO Action] читай в Telegraph', reply_markup=nav.newsMMOActionMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)


    #О боте для игр
    elif message.text == 'Кто я?':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Основная информация о боте указана в telegraph!', reply_markup=nav.newsWhoiambMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Соглашение':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Основная информация о пользовательском соглашении указана в telegraph!', reply_markup=nav.newsSoglbMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Профиль игрока
    elif message.text == 'Главное':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nВаш аккаунт: {0.first_name}'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nКоличество покупок: '
                                                     '\n'
                                                     f'\nВаш баланс: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб.'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Мои покупки':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nВаши покупки: '.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Баланс':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'\nВаш баланс: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб.'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)


    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_mess(message: types.Message):
        if is_number(message.text):
            message_money = int(message.text)
            if message_money >= 5:
                comment = str(message.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
                bill = p2p.bill(amount=message_money, lifetime=15, comment=comment)

                db.add_check(message.from_user.id, message_money, bill.bill_id)

                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Вам нужно отправить {message_money} руб. на наш счет QIWI\nСсылку: {bill.pay_url}\nУказав комментарий к оплате: {comment}", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Минимальная сумма для пополнения 5 руб.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите целое число")


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="top_up")
async def top_up(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Введите сумму для пополнения!")


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="check_")
async def check(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    bill = str(callback.data[6:])
    info = db.get_check(bill)
    if info != False:
        if str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == "PAID":
            user_money = db.user_money(callback.from_user.id)
            money = int(info[2])
            db.set_money(callback.from_user.id, user_money+money)
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Ваш счет пополнен! Напишите /start")
            db.delete_check(bill)

        else:
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Вы не оплатили счет!", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(False, bill=bill))
    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Счет не найден")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**config.py code**

```
TOKEN = "MyToken"
QIWI_TOKEN = "MyToken"
```

**murkaps.py code**

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

btnMain = KeyboardButton('Главное меню')

# ---Main Menu---
btnBuyCheat = KeyboardButton('️Купить читы')
btnNews = KeyboardButton('Hot Новости')
btnLifeHack = KeyboardButton('️Лайфхаки дня')
btnMyacc = KeyboardButton('Профиль')
btnAboutTheBot = KeyboardButton('О боте')
mainMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnBuyCheat, btnNews, btnLifeHack, btnMyacc, btnAboutTheBot)

btnTopUp = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пополнить", callback_data="top_up")
topUpMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
topUpMenu.insert(btnTopUp)

# ---Cheat For Game Menu---
btnCSGO = KeyboardButton('CS-GO')
btnDota2 = KeyboardButton('Dota2')
btnCODBO = KeyboardButton('Call Of Duty:Black Ops')
btnPUBG = KeyboardButton('PUBG')
btnST2 = KeyboardButton('Standoff2')
ChFoGaMeMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCSGO, btnDota2, btnCODBO, btnPUBG, btnST2,  btnMain)

# ---Cheat For Game Menu---
btnToday = KeyboardButton('Today')
btnYetday = KeyboardButton('Yesterday')
newsMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnToday, btnYetday, btnMain)

# ---Lifehack for Game Menu---
btnShoot = KeyboardButton('Шутеры')
btnMMORPG = KeyboardButton('ММОРПГ')
btnStrateg = KeyboardButton('Стратегии')
btnMMOA = KeyboardButton('MMO Action[скоро!]')
LiHaMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnShoot, btnMMORPG, btnStrateg, btnMMOA, btnMain)

# ---About The Bot Menu---
btnWhoiam = KeyboardButton('Кто я?')
btnSogl = KeyboardButton('Соглашение')
aboutthebotMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnWhoiam, btnSogl, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For CS-GO Menu---
btnCSBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[CS-GO]')
buyCSMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCSBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Dota2  Menu---
btnDota2Buy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Dota2]')
buyDota2Menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnDota2Buy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Call Of Duty:Black Ops  Menu---
btnCallOfDutyBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Call Of Duty:Black Ops]')
buyCallOfDutyMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCallOfDutyBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For PUBG  Menu---
btnPUBGBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[PUBG]')
buyPUBGMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnPUBGBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Standoff2  Menu---
btnStandoff2Buy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Standoff2]')
buyStandoff2Menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnStandoff2Buy, btnMain)

# ---NewsToday Menu---
btnToday = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsTMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnToday, btnMain)

# ---NewsYesterday Menu---
btnYesToday = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsYEMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnYesToday, btnMain)

# ---Шутеры Menu---
btnShoot = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsShootMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnShoot, btnMain)

# ---ММОРПГ Menu---
btnMMORPG = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsMMORPGMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMMORPG, btnMain)

# ---Стратегии---
btnStrategy = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsStrategyMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnStrategy, btnMain)

# ---MMO Action[скоро!] Menu---
btnMMOActionToday = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsMMOActionMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMMOActionToday, btnMain)

# ---About Bot Menu---
btnWhoiamb = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsWhoiambMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnWhoiamb, btnMain)

# ---Bot Agreement Menu---
btnSoglb = KeyboardButton('Читать')
newsSoglbMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnSoglb, btnMain)

# ---Profell Menu---
btnGlavn = KeyboardButton('Главное')
btnChek = KeyboardButton('Мои покупки')
btnBalans = KeyboardButton('Баланс')
myaccMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnGlavn, btnChek, btnBalans, btnMain)


# ---Popolnit Menu---
def buy_menu(isUrl = True, url="", bill=""):
    qiwiMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    if isUrl:
        btnUrlQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ссылка на оплату", url=url)
        qiwiMenu.insert(btnUrlQIWI)

    btnChekQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверить оплату", callback_data="check_"+bill)
    qiwiMenu.insert(btnChekQIWI)
    return qiwiMenu
```

**db.py code**

```
import _sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = _sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
           return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT money FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return int(result[0][0])

    def set_money(self, user_id, user_money):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET money = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_money, user_id))

    def add_check(self, user_id, money, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'check' ('user_id', 'money', 'bill_id') VALUES (?,?,?)", (user_id, money, bill_id,))

    def get_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'check' WHERE bill_id = ?", (bill_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            if not bool(len(result)):
                return False
            return result[0]

    def delete_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `check` WHERE `bill_id` = ?", (bill_id,))
```

***I could not find a solution to the problem, can someone tell me***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using states:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

class Payment(StatesGroup):
    wait_sum = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="top_up")
async def top_up(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Введите сумму для пополнения!")
    await Payment.wait_sum.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Payment.wait_sum)
async def bot_mess(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    #Your function for billing

    #After user gave you the number:
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: If I was helpful, you could mark my answer as a solution <3

Comment: Hello! A new error has appeared due to the fact that the processing and creation of a payment link is taking place, but the payment verification button does not work(
You can tell me, if necessary, I can create a new question...Please....

Comment: Do any errors show up?